# How to share Case record to owner's manager using Manager Groups

Tags: sharing, sharing-rule

I have this situation:

1. In Sharing Settings, Default Internal Access of Case object is set to "Private".
2. Roles are configured and is working fine. Users in upper roles are able to see records owned by users having lower role.
3. Sharing to Manager Groups is enabled.
4. I've created a Case Sharing Rule, where Owner of the specific role shares record to User in his Manager Groups.

In Step 4, I expect managers to be able to see records owned by their team, not only by role hierarchy but it does not work. What would be the steps to achieve this?